# What address book / CRM for Windows do you use?

Tags: address-book

I wish to have an address book where I can also record information about people and my interaction with them.

What services/software do you find useful for this task? How and Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Business Contact Manager with Outlook. It's a really good way to keep tracks of calls, meetings and notes from each customer I have.

I use the 2003 version and this one is free. Free to download and to use.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3aec8b42-6dc5-4922-9dfb-1c82237d6b62&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

I use Windows Contacts, works excellent and is compatible with many programs...also use Yahoo! Contacts, although not related, because its not Windows-based.  I use Outlook 2007 also...